# How to add custom header to outgoing SOAP payload using a Connected Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I need to add a custom header to every payload sent to one of the Connected Services in my projects with an HTTPS endpoint. That custom header will serve as authentication to the receiver. How can I do this?

I've tried to use `System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader` and `AddressHeader` with no luck. With SoapUI, adding a custom header to the request works fine.

This authentication method is new to the receiver. As also the HTTPS endpoint. In former request I was using `Basic Http Authentication` with a user and password. So, I've changed a bit to this to support an HTTPS binding code is:

```
BasicHttpsBinding basicAuthBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
basicAuthBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

EndpointAddress basicAuthEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://whatever");
MyConnectedService.MyOperationClient client = new MyConnectedService.MyOperationClient(basicAuthBinding, basicAuthEndpoint);

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";         
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";

client.send(payload);
```

I believe somewhere in here I need to add the custom header.

With this code I'm getting the expected `HTTP 401 - Unauthorized`.

Help appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept static custom header , you could try web.config(app.config).

```
 <endpoint address="http://ws-wuxipc-5077:4000/calculator" binding="basicHttpBinding"
  contract="ServiceInterface.CustomHeader" name="header">
  <headers>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" >
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>
        </wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">monMonDePasse</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce>sdsdsdlojhfdsdM5Nw==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2019-01-21T6:17:34Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </headers>
</endpoint>
```